# FB Access token on different php page

Tags: php, facebook

Iv been following some example code for a php facebook login using the facebook sdk, so far i have it logging in correctly etc. However after login the code states that i can redirect a user to a different php page using :

```
header('Location: mypage.php');
```

This works and the page loads etc, however the access token is a variable on the previous page and it seems insecure to pass the access token or session like so:

```
header("Location: mypage.php?token=".$accessToken);
```

The line on mypage.php that requires the access token is :

```
$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $accessToken);
//as i need to be able to call $user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

So i am now encountering a problem as im unsure how i am meant to access the information without passing variables to the other script via GET methods and parameters. Can anyone suggest how i could access this access token any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use sessions. (And btw., that Location header is incorrect - it requires an absolute URL per definition.)

Comment: im just using localhost atm and have added localhost to the app on fb. So i can access the variable in php via a session?

Comment: You can access what you put into the session.

Comment: Are you not using the official PHP SDK? That would take care of that automatically.

Comment: I have included the official facebook php sdk but as i said the token on the new php page is null but i will look into the php sections and see if i can access the token that way. If you post this as an answer and it works out i'll accept it as it seems to be what im looking for.

Comment: Actually the session was exactly what i need and its already working @CBroe thanks so much, post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So i am now encountering a problem as im unsure how i am meant to access the information without passing variables to the other script via GET methods and parameters.

Use sessions.

Session data is stored on the server, so it is not accessible from the outside. Only the session id (that allow figuring out which set of stored data belongs to which requesting client) is public; but the user won’t be able to get to any information stored in the session by any other means that your script.